# Issues with AutoLayout and MKMapView in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, maps, mapkit

I have a problem when I am setting constraints in my MkMapView, when I set them in a iPhone 7 emulator, it works very good, but when I change it to an iPhone 6 emulator or an iPad emulator, it keeps changing itself, I tried everything but the constraints won't work.

[image: when I set the constraints successfully]

[image: As soon as I change the model, it modifies itself]

please help

Comment: Please share a screenshot showing your contraints view.

Comment: Well, everything seems in order - you changed from smaller screen to bigger screen, so Interface Builder shows you (the orange lines) that the view will be bigger. All you need to do is refresh it (there is an icon above model selection for it, on the right) and the view will snap to fit the new screen size. If you actually run it on simulator/device you would have seen that everything is fine. I agree that Interface Builder should automatically refresh when changing device for preview, but well...

Answer (score 0):

In iphone7 emulator, have you got all blue lines in the edges of the screen. If you did't get,then you have applied wrong constraints.

Try **cmd+alt+=** shortcut to update the constraints. After this the constraints adjust themselves. Now,try to go to other emulators it will work.

Comment: it doesn't work :(, I even tried to open a new project, the same happens, the odd thing is that it only happens with a Map View, I added constraints to an Image View and it worked perfectly

Comment: can you share your project. I just need to check it out.